# Salesforce for Outlook & Attachments

Tags: attachment, salesforce-for-outlook

The documentation for SFO states that SFO supports attachments, if 'Always save email attachments' is ticked in the user's Email settings.  But if so - where does the attachment end up if SFO is used to attach mail to a Contact/Opportunity?  I tried this on my own user, and no attachment is attached to the Contact as far as I can see. Anyone else tried this and had problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addendum for this, I found this out. The Attachment is shown on the Parent Account of the Contact. Both on the Activity itself in Activity History and in the Notes & Attachments on the Account. If anyone else should run into this problem/misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't the attachments linked to the activity records itself instead of the contact?
So if you open up the e-mail in detail view via activity history on the contact?

Comment: Nope, just checked to see if it does ( sent myself a test email and added it to my contact).  The Activity Record does not show any attachments.  Going to log a case to see whether this is misconfigured somehow.

Comment: Addendum for this, I found this out.  The Attachment is shown on the Parent Account of the Contact.  Both on the Activity itself in Activity History and in the Notes & Attachments on the Account.
If anyone else should run into this problem/misunderstanding.